# Batch If and Else Error

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, automation

I have looked through a few of the questions on here and I was unable to find what I was looking for.  Hopefully I can get some clarification on this.. I have the following Batch Code Block:

```
:CommandCheck
If Exist java -version (goto start)Else
(echo !!Java not installed!! Installing supported version now)
goto install
```

But when I run this, it just closes  the command prompt.  I am trying to get it to test a certain command and if it fails to load, it goes to another part of the script and if it does exist, it goes elsewhere.  I have tested various methods mentioned here and else where but I cannot seem to get the working formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is worth mentioning that checking for a specific version of a certain piece of software is a varied and complex task, doubly so on Windows, and even more so with Batch scripting.

You could check for the exact path of the java executable, and assume it isn't installed if Windows can't find it.

```
:CommandCheck
    if not exist "c:\path\to\java.exe" (goto Install)
    goto Start
```

Also:

1. Don't forget double quotes when using IF EXIST
2. You may want to consider using CALLs instead of GOTOs.

Check out http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ and http://ss64.com/nt/ for more info on learning batch scripting.  And Stack Overflow of course :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I am trying to test if a command exists.  Would that too need to be in ""? I tried doing so and the check failed again.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "command".  Do you mean an input parameter i.e "yourscript.bat java yourfile.jar"?

Comment: Sure thing.  What I am trying to do is test the existence of a command in cmd.  In this case, I want to test "java -version".  If that doesn't exist, I am trying to get it to goto another part of the script. If it does exist, to goto another section as well. Hope that helps.

Comment: When you type 'java -version' on the command line, Windows was configured to "look for" java.exe in its installation directory (via the %PATH% environment variable) and execute it. So java is not actually a command like cls and help are, but a shorthand way of typing c:\path\to\java.exe.  I think my original answer may indeed be what you need.

Comment: *"Batch doesn't support an ELSE statement."* - That is patently false. BATCH absolutely supports IF ... ELSE ...

Comment: That was it! It worked beautifully.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

First off, your logic does not require an ELSE:

```
:CommandCheck
If exist "someFile" goto start
echo !!Java not installed!! Installing supported version now
goto install
```

But I don't think you are attempting to check for the existence of a file. Instead you are attempting to run the command `java -version`, and you want to goto start if that command was successful, and print a message and goto install if it failed.

You can use the `&&` operator to conditionally execute a command if the prior command succeeded. There is a coralary `||` to execute a command if the prior command failed.

```
someCommand && echo someCommand succeeded || echo someCommand failed
```

You only need one or the other. I also assume you do not need to see the ouput (or error message) of the `java -version` test.

```
:CommandCheck
java -version >nul 2>nul && goto start
echo !!Java not installed!! Installing supported version now
goto install
```

If you should ever want to truly use IF ELSE with parentheses, there are a couple important syntax rules

- The parentheses must be on the same lines as the preceding IF and ELSE
- There must be a space before each opening parenthesis

Here is an example

```
if exist "someFile" (
  echo someFile exists
) else (
  echo someFile does NOT exist
)
```

It can all be put on one line

```
if exist "someFile" (echo someFile exists)else (echo someFile does NOT exist)
```

The following fails because the opening parentheses are not preceded by a space, so `"someFIle"(` and `else(` are treated as tokens, which cannot work.

```
if exist "someFile"(echo someFile exists)else(echo someFile does NOT exist)
```

The following fails because the parentheses must be on the same lines as IF and ELSE

```
if exist "someFile"
  (echo someFile exists)
else
  (echo someFile does NOT exist)
```

Comment: That's some great info. I've made note for future reference. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a pause function at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, it didn't work.  It would still fail the check.